# Infinite connection between flash as3 and php

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, connection, infinite-loop

I have a big website and I want it to load new content once it is added to database. `Javascript's setInterval()` is not acceptable because of too many connections, `node.js` is not available for my `web hosting`, so I am wondering if it is possible to keep connection live between `flash as3` and `php`.

*How I Imagine it:*

- Firstly our website loaded basic content..
- Flash AS3 Connect to php and keeps the connection live..
- When users add new information AS3 calls Javascript and add new Information to the website..

Comment: Um have you ever heard of an open socket connection? HTML5 should also support that.

Comment: @The_asMan yes but I didn't work with it before, can you show me a little example on this?

Comment: There is just no little example. Just google HTML5 socket or google AS3 socket

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if your web hosting allow a live executable acting as a permanent server.

Otherwise, you can use Comet to trigger an async request to the server.

http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start